# How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?

Tags: r, csv, r-faq

I have a csv file where some of the numerical values are expressed as strings with commas as thousand separator, e.g. `"1,513"` instead of `1513`. What is the simplest way to read the data into R?

I can use `read.csv(..., colClasses="character")`, but then I have to strip out the commas from the relevant elements before converting those columns to numeric, and I can't find a neat way to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I want to use R rather than pre-processing the data as it makes it easier when the data are revised. Following Shane's suggestion of using `gsub`, I think this is about as neat as I can do:

```
x <- read.csv("file.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses="character")
col2cvt <- 15:41
x[,col2cvt] <- lapply(x[,col2cvt],function(x){as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))})
```

Comment: Doesn't colClasses="char" force all columns to be char in which case the others besides 15:41 are also char?  Maybe letting read.csv() decide and then converting those that in cols 15:41 may get you 'more' numeric columns.

Comment: Yes, but as my question noted, all the other columns are character. I could use as.is=TRUE instead which would be more general. But letting read.csv() decide by using the default arguments is not helpful because it will convert anything that looks like a character into a factor which causes hassles for the numeric columns as then they don't convert properly using as.numeric().

Comment: You should consider setting the dec= argument in read table to ".". That is the default for read.csv2 but comma is hardwired into read.csv().

Answer (score 163):

Not sure about how to have `read.csv` interpret it properly, but you can use `gsub` to replace `","` with `""`, and then convert the string to `numeric` using `as.numeric`:

```
y <- c("1,200","20,000","100","12,111")
as.numeric(gsub(",", "", y))
# [1]  1200 20000 100 12111
```

This was [also answered previously on R-Help](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg62846.html) (and in [Q2 here](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg69442.html)).

Alternatively, you can pre-process the file, for instance with `sed` in unix.

Comment: I guess, when having those numbers, we will almost exclusively deal with integers - thus I think using `as.integer` might be the better choice in most cases?

Answer (score 69):

You can have read.table or read.csv do this conversion for you semi-automatically. First create a new class definition, then create a conversion function and set it as an "as" method using the setAs function like so:

```
setClass("num.with.commas")
setAs("character", "num.with.commas", 
        function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", from) ) )
```

Then run read.csv like:

```
DF <- read.csv('your.file.here', 
   colClasses=c('num.with.commas','factor','character','numeric','num.with.commas'))
```

Comment: This is very nice trick. It could be used for on-import conversion (for example converting Y/N values to logical vector using `setAs("character", "logical.Y.N", function(from) c(Y=TRUE,N=FALSE)[from] )`).

Comment: The same trick use in [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5068705/168747). And to add: one could use either `setClass("num.with.commas")` or `suppresMessage(setAs(.....))` to avoid message about missing class.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for sharing this handy function. Upon execution I am getting the following warning: in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"character","num.with.commas"’: no definition for class “num.with.commas” Any idea what the issue is here, I have your code word for word?

Comment: I checked out the similar problem link and saw that I need to set the class! Thanks for the neat trick.

Answer (score 17):

This question is several years old, but I stumbled upon it, which means maybe others will.

The [`readr`](https://github.com/hadley/readr) library / package has some nice features to it.  One of them is a nice way to interpret "messy" columns, like these.

```
library(readr)
read_csv("numbers\n800\n\"1,800\"\n\"3500\"\n6.5",
          col_types = list(col_numeric())
        )
```

This yields

Source: local data frame [4 x 1]

```
  numbers
    (dbl)
1   800.0
2  1800.0
3  3500.0
4     6.5
```

---

An important point when reading in files:  you either have to pre-process, like the comment above regarding `sed`, or you have to process **while reading**.  Often, if you try to fix things after the fact, there are some dangerous assumptions made that are hard to find.  (Which is why flat files are so evil in the first place.)

For instance, if I had not flagged the `col_types`, I would have gotten this:

```
> read_csv("numbers\n800\n\"1,800\"\n\"3500\"\n6.5")
Source: local data frame [4 x 1]

  numbers
    (chr)
1     800
2   1,800
3    3500
4     6.5
```

(Notice that it is now a `chr` (`character`) instead of a `numeric`.)

Or, more dangerously, if it were long enough and most of the early elements did not contain commas:

```
> set.seed(1)
> tmp <- as.character(sample(c(1:10), 100, replace=TRUE))
> tmp <- c(tmp, "1,003")
> tmp <- paste(tmp, collapse="\"\n\"")
```

(such that the last few elements look like:)

```
\"5\"\n\"9\"\n\"7\"\n\"1,003"
```

Then you'll find trouble reading that comma at all!

```
> tail(read_csv(tmp))
Source: local data frame [6 x 1]

     3"
  (dbl)
1 8.000
2 5.000
3 5.000
4 9.000
5 7.000
6 1.003
Warning message:
1 problems parsing literal data. See problems(...) for more details.
```

Answer (score 15):

We can also use `readr::parse_number`, the columns must be characters though. If we want to apply it for multiple columns we can loop through columns using `lapply`

```
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], readr::parse_number)
df

#  a        b        c
#1 a    12234       12
#2 b      123  1234123
#3 c     1234     1234
#4 d 13456234    15342
#5 e    12312 12334512
```

Or use `mutate_at` from `dplyr` to apply it to specific variables.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(2:3, readr::parse_number)
#Or
df %>% mutate_at(vars(b:c), readr::parse_number)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5], 
                 b = c("12,234", "123", "1,234", "13,456,234", "123,12"),
                 c = c("12", "1,234,123","1234", "15,342", "123,345,12"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is arguably the easiest and most modern way to deal with such numbers.

Answer (score 8):

#### a `dplyr` solution using `mutate_all` and pipes

say you have the following:

```
> dft
Source: local data frame [11 x 5]

   Bureau.Name Account.Code   X2014   X2015   X2016
1       Senate          110 158,000 211,000 186,000
2       Senate          115       0       0       0
3       Senate          123  15,000  71,000  21,000
4       Senate          126   6,000  14,000   8,000
5       Senate          127 110,000 234,000 134,000
6       Senate          128 120,000 159,000 134,000
7       Senate          129       0       0       0
8       Senate          130 368,000 465,000 441,000
9       Senate          132       0       0       0
10      Senate          140       0       0       0
11      Senate          140       0       0       0
```

and want to remove commas from the year variables X2014-X2016, and
convert them to numeric. also, let's say X2014-X2016 are read in as
factors (default)

```
dft %>%
    mutate_all(funs(as.character(.)), X2014:X2016) %>%
    mutate_all(funs(gsub(",", "", .)), X2014:X2016) %>%
    mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(.)), X2014:X2016)
```

`mutate_all` applies the function(s) inside `funs` to the specified columns

I did it sequentially, one function at a time (if you use multiple
functions inside `funs` then you create additional, unnecessary columns)

Comment: `mutate_each` is deprecated. Do you want to update your answer with `mutate_at` or similar?

Answer (score 6):

"Preprocess" in R:

```
lines <- "www, rrr, 1,234, ttt \n rrr,zzz, 1,234,567,987, rrr"
```

Can use `readLines` on a `textConnection`. Then remove only the commas that are between digits:

```
gsub("([0-9]+)\\,([0-9])", "\\1\\2", lines)

## [1] "www, rrr, 1234, ttt \n rrr,zzz, 1234567987, rrr"
```

It's als useful to know but not directly relevant to this question that commas as decimal separators can be handled by read.csv2 (automagically) or read.table(with setting of the 'dec'-parameter).

Edit: Later I discovered how to use colClasses by designing a new class. See:

[How to load df with 1000 separator in R as numeric class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088144/how-to-load-df-with-1000-separator-in-r-as-numeric-class/25090565#25090565)

Comment: Thanks, this was a good pointer but it does not work for digits that contain several decimal marks, e.g. 1,234,567.89 - needed to work around this problem to import a google spreadsheet into R, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020171/3096626 for a simple function that does the job for multiple decimal marks

Answer (score 6):

Using read_delim function, which is part of **readr** library, you can specify additional parameter:

```
locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")

read_delim("filetoread.csv", ";", locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
```

*Semicolon in second line means that read_delim will read csv semicolon separated values.

This will help to read all numbers with a comma as proper numbers.

Regards

Mateusz Kania

Answer (score 4):

If number is separated by "." and decimals by "," (1.200.000,00) in calling `gsub` you must `set fixed=TRUE as.numeric(gsub(".","",y,fixed=TRUE))`

Answer (score 3):

A very convenient way is `readr::read_delim`-family. Taking the example from here:
  [Importing csv with multiple separators into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925783/importing-csv-with-multiple-separators-into-r) you can do it as follows:

```
txt <- 'OBJECTID,District_N,ZONE_CODE,COUNT,AREA,SUM
1,Bagamoyo,1,"136,227","8,514,187,500.000000000000000","352,678.813105723350000"
2,Bariadi,2,"88,350","5,521,875,000.000000000000000","526,307.288878142830000"
3,Chunya,3,"483,059","30,191,187,500.000000000000000","352,444.699742995200000"'

require(readr)
read_csv(txt) # = read_delim(txt, delim = ",")
```

Which results in the expected result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  OBJECTID District_N ZONE_CODE  COUNT        AREA      SUM
     <int>      <chr>     <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1        1   Bagamoyo         1 136227  8514187500 352678.8
2        2    Bariadi         2  88350  5521875000 526307.3
3        3     Chunya         3 483059 30191187500 352444.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think preprocessing is the way to go. You could use [Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) which has a regular expression replace option.

For example, if your file were like this:

```
"1,234","123","1,234"
"234","123","1,234"
123,456,789
```

Then, you could use the regular expression `"([0-9]+),([0-9]+)"` and replace it with `\1\2`

```
1234,"123",1234
"234","123",1234
123,456,789
```

Then you could use  `x <- read.csv(file="x.csv",header=FALSE)` to read the file.

Comment: Anything you can script, you should.  Doing it by hand introduces the opportunity for error, as well as not being very reproducible.