# processing negative number in "accounting" format

Tags: r, finance, negative-number

I have dataset, which negative value is presented with a bracket around the number i.e. `(10)==-10`, it is in csv format, how can I process it so that R will interpret the `(10)` as `-10`? Thank you.

UPDATE
I know I can work it out by replacing `(` as `-`, remove `)`, and use `as.numeric` afterwards, but is there a more elegant way for this issue?

Comment: At the moment, I can't think of a more elegant way than that suggested in your edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you create an "as.acntngFmt" method for the accounting format, you can read (or perhaps re-read with a text connection using colClasses("acnt").

```
 setClass("acntngFmt")
 # [1] "acntngFmt"
 setAs("character", "acntngFmt",
    function(from) as.numeric( gsub("\\)", "", gsub("\\(", "-", from))))

  Input <- "A, B, C
  (1.76), 1%, 3.50€
  2.00, 2%, 4.77€
  3.000, 3% , €5.68"

   DF <- read.csv(textConnection(Input), header = TRUE,
     colClasses = c("acntngFmt", "character", "character"))
   str(DF)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: num  -1.76 2 3
 $ B: chr  "1%" "2%" "3%"
 $ C: chr  "3.50€" "4.77€" "€5.68"
```

Comment: You could gain speed up using `fixed=TRUE` mode of regular expression: `as.numeric(sub(")", "", sub("(", "-", from, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE))`.

Comment: You are right and I think sub might be more appropriate than gsub as well since this would be applied element-wise.

Comment: Building on 42-'s answer, code to handle embedded commas in the accounting format: `setClass("acntngFmt")
clean.acc <- function(from) {
  as.numeric(gsub("\\,", "", gsub("\\)", "", gsub("\\(", "-", from))))
}
setAs("character", "acntngFmt", clean.acc)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the surrounding parentheses will be the only ones in the unit, you can create a function to deal with them:

```
test <- c(10, "(10)", 5)
negative_paren <- function(vec){
  #the backspace escapes the special "(" character
  vec <- gsub("\\(","-",vec) 
  vec <- gsub("\\)","",vec)
  vec <- as.numeric(vec)
  return(vec)
}
negative_paren(test)
[1]  10 -10   5
```