# Trouble converting character to numeric in R

Tags: r

I've pulled a table from Wikipedia, but I'm getting a bunch of junk with the population numbers I'm looking for. For instance, I get **"!B9840748934017Â 8,244,910"** when the actual number I'm after is 8,244,910 only. I've cleaned up the character vector with regex, using `sub('![[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]', '', x)`

This works fine, leaving me with the character vector "8,244,910". When I try to convert it to numeric using `as.numeric`, however, it gets coerced to NA, and I'm unable to get an integer, no matter what conversions I try. Any thoughts?

Comment: Strip out the commas too, before converting to numeric.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even cross my mind, but that solved it.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. What page are you trying to get the data from? Just curious if there's a more direct way.

Comment: "Pulled a table" how, exactly?

Comment: somewhat related question: [How to read a csv file in R where some numbers contain commas?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1523126/59470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
as.numeric(gsub('![[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]', '', x))
```

The problem is that you have commas in the output of your first attempt. Those need to be removed before converting to `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 3):

Ananda's solution does get the job done but something may go wrong:

- `[:punct:]` also includes dot character `(.)` which is valid part of `numeric`;
- bulky regex is hard to read and it's easier to break things up:

  `# remove junk`

  `num_temp = sub('![[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]', '', x)`

  `# remove all commas from numerics`

  `num = gsub(",", "", num_temp)`

Comment: +1, Good point about stripping decimals, but don't necessarily agree about having to break this problem into two steps....