# R: read.csv parse dates

Tags: r, parsing, datetime

The function `read.csv` in R allows you to pass in colClasses in order to speed up the parsing process.  One of the classes that you are allowed to pass in is `Date`. My data file has a date column in the `%m/%d/%Y` format - normally I read this in as a character vector using `read.csv`, then after that is complete I convert the column using `as.Date(foo, "%m/%d/%Y")`.

Is there a way to pass a custom date format to `read.csv` so the date conversion can be done inside `read.csv`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right this is an exact duplicate

Comment: Also basically answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas/3611619#3611619