# How to read a tsv file in R where some elements contain \t?

Tags: r, validation, bigdata

A question closer to mine was asked ans answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas/1523235#1523235).

My problem if fairly simple: I need to import in R a .tsv file, but I cannot because some elements contain a \t so that I received an error like:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 34 did not have 6 elements
```

One way to proceed would be to use gsub in order to replace the \ts. But the file is quite big in size, around 11GB, and doing this pre-processing would probably be too much for my machine. Any idea about a possible short-cut here?

Some context: at the end I need to import the whole dataset into a SQL database; I could do it without doing this conversion but at that point I would have the same problem.

Comment: Use a tool that is designed for this purpose such as `awk` or `sed`. Search with either: [r] preprocess sed` OR `[r] preprocess awk`. I cannot tell if you already understand that `\t` is a tab in R but that `/t` is not.

Comment: @DWin I just fixed those /t, my bad.

Comment: So perhaps the problem is that you are using the incorrect `read.delim` call. If your file has `\t`'s, then it IS tab-separated as its extension suggests, and such files can be read with `sep="\t"` and perhaps combinations of `comment.char=""` and `quote=""` and `fill =TRUE`.

Comment: It was the quote, thank you very much!