# How to use read.table if data are thousand separated by dots

Tags: r

I would like to read.table from a csv file that has dots as thousand separators.

Resulting numbers should be numeric.

This is somewhat complicated as `read.table` allows to configure decimal signs and quote signs but not thousand separators.

The command `gsub(input[10,10],pattern='[.]',replacement='')` could delete the dots but transforms everything to characters. The conversation with `as.numeric` does work for single numbers:

```
> input[4,4]
[1] 1.742
97 Levels: 0 1.034 1.132 1.137 1.153 1.164 1.178 1.190 1.208 1.251 1.282 ... 950
> gsub(input[4,4],pattern='[.]',replacement='')
[1] "1742"
> as.numeric(gsub(input[4,4],pattern='[.]',replacement=''))
[1] 1742
```

but not for tables, as `gsub(input,pattern='[.]',replacement='')` yields

`…
[4] "c(17, 21, 31, 38, 39, 48, 56, 52, 57, 63, 66, 68, 71, 76, 78, 79, 75, 77, 74, 73, 65, 64, 55, 50, 45, 43, 34, 36, 44, 42, 32, 5, 96, 10, 9, 6, 22, 53, 54, 14, 15, 16, 24, 18, 23, 33, 25, 28, 35, 47, 49, 51, 62, 70, 72, 69, 67, 58, 26, 94, 93, 97, 8, 41, 37, 46, 29, 40, 27, 30, 20, 19, 12, 13, 11, 7, 3, 4, 2, 95, 92, 90, 89, 87, 86, 83, 81, 80, 61, 60, 59, 91, 82, 88, 84, 85, 1, 1, 1, 1)" …`

which is a vector of `NA` if converted to numeric. Furthermore, something else seems to be wrong with that command since most values are larger than thousand.

Is there anything else that could be useful, besides editing the original `.csv` files?

Comment: Does using `quote = "\""` as an argument in `read.csv` help, i.e. if the numbers are quoted inside the file, so the thousands separator is contained within quotes that should fix the problem. Show us some sample input data if it doesn't help.

Comment: I'd do that `as.numeric` and `gsub` trick with `apply`.

Comment: The conversion to numeric doesn't work because your data has been converted to factors. Try adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `read.table()`.

Comment: -1 for not providing example data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas/3611619#3611619), just change the coma (`,`) to the escaped period (`\\.`) in the `gsub` call to remove the periods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input is of type character to begin with, this should work -

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[,input := as.numeric(gsub(input,pattern='[.]',replacement='')), by = 'input']
```

Comment: I don't quite follow why you need a `by=input` here.

Comment: If you run it without the by, it gsubs across the input column together instead of doing it row by row. The `by` helps make sure that only one value is passed to gsub instead of a whole vector.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide an example? Already the OP doesn't. I seem to have a hard time wrapping my head around this problem...

Comment: `gsub` is vectorised and `input` is a vector. So, I really don't understand what's the problem with just doing: `dt[, input := as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", as.character(input)))]`.

Comment: `library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
a = c("qweqwe","cbc","cvbcva","cvbcva","cbc")
)

dt[,something := grep(x = a,pattern = "a")]
dt[,something := grep(x = a,pattern = "a"), by = "a"]`

Comment: (I don't code that fast, I was already working on an example) :)

Comment: What you did is basically: `dt[grep("a", a), something := 1L]`, isn't it?

Comment: The output looks the same. I suppose that's because the where part operates row-by-row while the select/update part works does not?

Comment: I don't quite follow your last line. The output looks the same because we're doing same thing. Except that you perform a `grep` on *each group* (using `by`), which'll be costly.

Comment: Oh, I just realised that this problem won't arise with `gsub`. "gsub is vectorised and input is a vector." Blah. Sorry/Thanks.