# Loading dataframe containing useless characters in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

I have an executable that outputs a table every time
it is called by R. I then want to load the dataframe in R,
but it contains lots of "!", for instance:

```
! A B C
  0 1 2
  3 3 2
  1 1 1
!
  3 4 2
  2 2 3
  5 2 5
!
  3 4 2
  .....
```

so that I get:

```
sim_stat <- read.table("C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/Forest/Formind/formind-model/result/result.dia")
# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
#  line 2 did not have 11 elements
```

I need to read the data in R every second more or less, so is there a fast way to
remove those "!" ? I am working in Windows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have `!` treated as a comment character:

```
read.table(file="...", comment.char="!")
```

That *will get rid of the header*, or any other lines with an extraneous !. If you have data in a line with !, and you want to ignore the ! but keep the rest, there is this long workaround:

```
> read.table(text=gsub("!", "", readChar("test.txt", file.info("test.txt")$size)), header=TRUE)
  A B C
1 0 1 2
2 3 3 2
3 1 1 1
4 3 4 2
5 2 2 3
6 5 2 5
7 3 4 2
```

Obviously replacing "test.txt" with your file name in both instances, and "!" with whatever character(s) to be ignored.

Comment: That did, many thanks! In my case it commented out the first row,
but that's fine. It would be nice to have a "ignore.char" option!

Comment: @MatteoFasiolo Oh yeah it would take away your header! But that fix is easy as I'm sure you've figured out. `ignore.char` would be nice for this situation.

Comment: Great! This "gsub" trick will certainly turn out to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same idea as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas/3611619#3611619), just remove the exclamation mark (or any other unwanted characters) instead of the commas.