# R: Importing read.csv with numeric format

Tags: r, csv

Reading CSV data with R, in column 11 have data in the formats "1,022.00" and "516.00" and they must be "numerics" or "double"

```
dados201702 <- read.csv("dataset.csv", 
                        header = TRUE, 
                        sep = "\t", 
                        dec = ".",
                        colClasses = c("character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "character", 
                                       "numeric",
                                       "character"))
```

I want to import column 11 as numeric or double however error occurs:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
>   = dec, scan() expected 'a real', got '1,022.00'

Comment: Show us some example data to work with

Comment: Please clarify what you are are trying to ask. You may want to check out the [asking guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically the section on [minimal, complete, and verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to import column 11 as numeric or double however error occurs: "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, scan() expected 'a real', got '1,022.00'"

Comment: Would there be a large downside to reading that column as character then converting that column to numeric in the same step? i.e. `dados201702$column11 %<>% as.numeric`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your data contains a 1000s separator where the `,` is giving you problems. You can either read in the `data.frame` and convert the relevant columns using `gsub` or you can define a new class definition as suggested in one of the following links:

- [How to load df with 1000 separator in R as numeric class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088144/how-to-load-df-with-1000-separator-in-r-as-numeric-class/25090565#25090565)
- [processing negative number in "accounting" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068705/processing-negative-number-in-accounting-format/5069649#5069649)

Here we define a new class that removes the commas (the 1000 separator).

```
setClass("MyNum")
setAs("character", "MyNum", 
      function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", from) ))
indata <- read.csv("tst.txt", , 
                   header = TRUE, 
                   sep = "\t", 
                   dec = ".", 
                   colClasses=c(rep("character", 10), "MyNum", "character"))
```

Alternatively just use `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", from) )` where `from` is the vector containing the 1000s separator.