# how to read a csv with a timestamp field?

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a csv file that has a field `Ts` containing ISO8601 time stamp values (E.g. 2014-12-01T18:54:22.973+0000).

I have seen that you can specify the class of columns:

```
kd <- read.csv( "my.csv", colClasses=c( "Ts"="?"  ))
```

However, I can't find how to declare a timestamp field.

**Question:** How can I specify that this field is a time stamp?

Comment: You need to use `setAs` to make a function that can handle that colClass.  e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3611619/967840, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10823641/967840

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the .csv file directly into a time series object, you can use the function `read.zoo()` from the `zoo` package. This internally calls `read.table()` (rather than `read.csv`) and then converts the specified time index column(s). See `?read.zoo` and `vignette("zoo-read", package = "zoo")`.

An example with time stamps like yours is:

```
csv <-
"x,y,timestamp
0,1,2014-12-01T18:54:22.973+0000
1,2,2014-12-01T19:43:11.862+0000"
read.zoo(text = csv, sep = ",", header = TRUE, index = "timestamp",
  format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z", tz = "GMT")
```

And this yields a `zoo` series with `POSIXct` time stamps:

```
                    x y
2014-12-01 18:54:22 0 1
2014-12-01 19:43:11 1 2
```

(Of course, the `text = csv` would have to be replaced by something like `file = "my.csv"` if you are reading a .csv file from the disk rather than a text string from within R.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know of a way to do it directly on the read, but as a workaround (until someone more knowledgeable answers) you can do the conversion afterwords:

```
kd <- read.csv("my.csv")
%  Assume that the timestamp column in the csv file has the header 'timestamp'

kd$newtimestamp <- strptime(kd$timestamp,format="%FT%H:%M:%OS%z")

%  By default this will convert all times to your timezone 
%  but you can control the conversion through the tx argument e.g. tx='GMT'
```