# t X axis on R doesn't plot in order

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Using this dataframe:

```
names   x   y   MV

1   O4  -0,33   -1,2    -5,2
2   O9,5 -0,305 -1,1    -3,6
3   B0  -0,3    -1,08   -3,25
4   B0,5 -0,28  -1  -2,6
5   B1,5    -0,25   -0,9    -2,1
6   B2,5    -0,22   -0,8    -1,5
7   B3  -0,2    -0,69   -1,1
8   B6  -0,15   -0,5    -0,2
9   B8  -0,1    -0,3    0,6
10  B9,5    -0,05   -0,1    1,1
11  A0,5    0   0,01    1,5
12  A2  0,05    0,05    1,7
13  A4  0,1 0,08    1,9
14  A5  0,15    0,09    2,1
15  A7  0,2 0,1 2,4
16  A8  0,25    0,07    2,55
17  F0  0,3 0,03    2,8
18  F2  0,35    0   3,1
19  F4  0,4 -0,01   3,4
20  F8  0,5 0   4,1
21  G0  0,6 0,08    4,7
22  G6  0,7 0,23    5,2
23  K0  0,8 0,42    5,8
24  K2  0,9 0,63    6,3
25  K3,5    1   0,86    6,7
26  K4,5    1,1 1,03    7,1
27  K5,5    1,2 1,13    7,5
28  K6,5    1,3 1,2 8
29  M0  1,4 1,22    8,8
```

Here is my Code:

```
df <- read.table(file = "Pasta1.txt", sep = "\t", header = T)
star <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=1)) +
  geom_point(alpha=1, size=5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=names),hjust=-0.4, vjust=0.8) +
  xlab("\n (B-V)0") +
  ylab("(U-B)0 \n") +
theme_bw() +
  theme( axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12),
    legend.title =element_blank() ,
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
star + ggtitle("Diagrama Cor - Cor para Estrelas do Aglomerado Galático NGC6025 \n")
```

[image: Plot output]

The problem is that :
The first 10 data points are plotted inverted the 10º point is ploted first and so on until the 11º point and then it came back to normal, ploting the 12º, 13º.

I am trying to plot in the order it is on the dataframe and I am seeking a method to make the negative values in the Y graph be shown on the top, and the positive numbers on the bottom.

Could you help me please?

Comment: In fact yes, my X's and Y's are factors

Comment: sorry deleted comment.. ok so you need to convert them to numeric. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas. Also look at the`dec` argument of `read.table`

Comment: using as.numeric it interestingly show my exactly the order my X was ploted:
> as.numeric(df$x)
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

Comment: You can (and often do) get misleading results by just using `as.numeric()` on a `factor` variable .. it returns the levels rather than the values.

Comment: Just using the dec argument in read.table I was able to fix the order problem in values.

Comment: Jezzzz I cant imagine just 5 letters fix everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like the problem is that your data is not `numeric`. Due to the comma, it is being read in as `character` and then converted to a `factor`.

You can change the variables to numeric by substituting out the comma for a period, and then converting to numeric, or by using the `dec` argument of `read.table` to declare that the comma is used for the decimal point.

An example, on your data

```
test <- tempfile()

writeLines("names   x   y   MV
1   O4  -0,33   -1,2    -5,2
            2   O9,5 -0,305 -1,1    -3,6
            3   B0  -0,3    -1,08   -3,25c
            4   B0,5 -0,28  -1  -2,6
            5   B1,5    -0,25   -0,9    -2,1
            6   B2,5    -0,22   -0,8    -1,5
            7   B3  -0,2    -0,69   -1,1
            8   B6  -0,15   -0,5    -0,2
            9   B8  -0,1    -0,3    0,6
            10  B9,5    -0,05   -0,1    1,1
            11  A0,5    0   0,01    1,5
            12  A2  0,05    0,05    1,7
            13  A4  0,1 0,08    1,9
            14  A5  0,15    0,09    2,1
            15  A7  0,2 0,1 2,4
            16  A8  0,25    0,07    2,55
            17  F0  0,3 0,03    2,8
            18  F2  0,35    0   3,1
            19  F4  0,4 -0,01   3,4
            20  F8  0,5 0   4,1
            21  G0  0,6 0,08    4,7
            22  G6  0,7 0,23    5,2
            23  K0  0,8 0,42    5,8
            24  K2  0,9 0,63    6,3
            25  K3,5    1   0,86    6,7
            26  K4,5    1,1 1,03    7,1
            27  K5,5    1,2 1,13    7,5
            28  K6,5    1,3 1,2 8
            29  M0  1,4 1,22    8,8", test)
```

Just read in specifying the decimal point as a comma

```
df <- read.table(test, sep="", dec=",")
```

Or convert to numeric (see [How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas))

```
df2 <- read.table(test, sep="")

df2[2:4] <- lapply(df2[2:4], function(X) as.numeric(gsub(",",".", X)))
```