# How to read data file, containing monetary values, using R

Tags: r, import

I have a simple txt file with some data that I need to read using `R`.

My file contains these rows :

```
a,      b,               c,    e
"1",    €57,000.00,      5,    10FEB2015
"K",    €0.00,           6,    15APR2016
"C",    €1,444,055.00,   6,    15APR2016
```

As you can see : the column `b` is a monetary value containing a thousands separator `,` which is the same delimiter for data (`sep=","`).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator?rq=1

Comment: Are the decimals (cents?) on the Euros always `.00`?

Comment: I was thinking if we find the end of the monetary value properly, then we can just add quotes to it and read it normally.  It just needs to be quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)
The cents are not always .00 :(

Answer (score 2):

sometimes you have to do it line-by-line:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

lines <- 'a,b,c,e
"1",€57,000.00,5,10FEB2015
"K",€0.00,6,15APR2016
"C",€1,444,055.00,6,15APR2016'

dat <- readLines(textConnection(lines))

# we need the column names
cols <- stri_split_regex(dat[1], ",")[[1]]

# regular expression capture groups can do the hard work
map_df(stri_match_all_regex(dat[2:length(dat)], 
                     '^"([[:alnum:]]+)",€([[:digit:],]+\\.[[:digit:]]{2}),([[:digit:]]+),(.*)$'),
  function(x) {
    setNames(rbind.data.frame(x[2:length(x)], 
                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
             cols)
  }
) -> df

# proper types
df$b <- as.numeric(stri_replace_all_regex(df$b, ",", ""))
df$e <- as.Date(df$e, "%d%b%Y")

str(df)

## Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ a: chr  "1" "K" "C"
##  $ b: num  57000 0 1444055
##  $ c: chr  "5" "6" "6"
##  $ e: Date, format: "2015-02-10" "2016-04-15" ...
```