# read csv setting fields with spaces to NA

Tags: regex, r, read.csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
A, B,  C, 
1, 2 1, 3,
3, 1, 0, 
4, 1, 0 5,
 ...
```

is it possible to set the na.string to assign all fields with space to NA (e.g. something like `regex` `function(x){x[grep(patt="\\ ", x)]<-NA;x`}), i.e.

```
A, B, C,
1, NA, 3,
3, 1, 0,
4, 1, NA,
```

Comment: Could you have a field contain only spaces, or will you always have at least another character?

Comment: there are no fields with only spaces -- always have at least other characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the columns and set it to `NA` by converting to `numeric`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.numeric)
```

NOTE: Here, I assumed that the columns are `character` class.  If it is `factor`, do `lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: it turns all the numeric fields to string, i.e. `"1", NA, "3"` instead of `1, NA, 3`

Comment: as.numeric! should have thought of this simple method! huge thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Variation on @akrun's answer (which I like).

```
library(dplyr)
read.csv("test.csv", colClasses="character") %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric))
```

This reads the file assuming all columns are `character`, then converts all to `numeric` with `mutate_each` from `dplyr`.

Using `colClasses="numeric"` already in the read call didn't work (and I don't know why :( ), since

```
> as.numeric("2 1")
[1] NA
```

From [How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator) we learn that we can make a new function to do the conversion.

```
setAs("character", "numwithspace", function(from) as.numeric(from) )
read.csv("test.csv", colClasses="numwithspace")
```

which gives

```
  A  B  C
1 1 NA  3
2 3  1  0
3 4  1 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this would translate in [r](/questions/tagged/r), but I would use the following regex to match fields containing spaces :

```
[^, ]+ [^, ]+
```

Which is :

- some characters other than a comma or a space (`[^, ]+`)
- followed by a space ()
- and some more characters other than a comma or a space (`[^, ]+`)

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/oG4zN8/2).