# Reading file containing numerical values and unknown errors (random strings) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Some `.csv` files with numerical data I work with contain errors, each error is marked as random string, for example after reading in, data frame could look like that :

```
set.seed(123)
rand.str <-  paste0(letters[sample(10)], collapse="")
wrong.output <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(4:5, rand.str, 7:8), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

in this case proper output is :

```
proper.output <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(4:5, NA, 7:8))
```

after reading with `read.csv` each column with at least one character value is treated as `character` column.

Can I mark errors (random strings) as `NA`s while reading-in file? If not, what is the most convenient, proper or fastest method for subsetting them with `NA`'s ?

There is `na.strings` argument in `read.csv`, but it is the solution only in simpler cases where it can be used like: `na.strings=c("-", "unavailable")`

(can't see any duplicate, so I guess there is simple, workaround)

`colClasses` suggestion does not work

```
read.csv("test.txt", sep=",", colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"))
```

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     scan() expected 'a real', got 'chdgfajibe'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'test.txt'

Comment: have you tried setting `colClasses=c("numeric")` within `read.csv` ?

Comment: yes and does not work :

Answer (score 1):

I adapted this solution from a different solution for csv reading which is 7 years back. I thought it is a cleaner solution. It gives your desired output.

```
setClass("Alpha")
# replacing words with empty characters
setAs("character", "Alpha", 
      function(from) as.numeric(gsub('[[:alpha:]]+', '', from) ) )
read.csv('data.csv', colClasses = c('numeric','Alpha'))
```

*output*

```
  a  b
1 1  4
2 2  5
3 3 NA
4 4  7
5 5  8
```

Source: [How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator)

Answer (score 0):

solution is :

`wrong.output[] <- lapply(wrong.output, as.numeric)`