# CSV is taking dots as thousand separator instead of commas

Tags: excel, csv

I am downloading .csv files in remote server. It is taking the thousand separator as `.` instead of  `,`. How I can rectify this?

Comment: Well, a *comma* separates values, which is why it is called a *Comma Separated Values* document...

Comment: This is just for displaying purposes, right? 'Cause the stored values should contain neither of these signs.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest looking at these two questions that have already been answered:

[How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator?rq=1)

[Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file?rq=1)

I am not sure what you are doing with the exported file, but another option would be to remove the "thousand separator" on the file before exporting it as csv, then reformatting it after you have performed your action.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys!!