# Scale Issue of bar chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a bar chart to show my dataset. There is a issue about the scale of the bar chart, here is my plot:

[image]

Here is part of my data [image: Data]
I don't know why the biggest number is on the bottom and the small number is on the top. How can I fix it?
Here are the codes:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat1) + geom_bar(aes(dat1$X...Country,dat1$X2017),stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Look like your data is stored as character/factors rather than numbers. You should supply a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can confirm.

Comment: could you please provide part of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your X2007 and X2008 columns are stored as factors, but you probably want them to be numeric. If you coerce a factor to a numeric, you will probably get unexpected results. So I'd recommend coercing to character and then to numeric. The commas present a problem there, so after converting to character, we'll remove the commas, then convert to numeric.

`dat1$X2007 <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(dat1$X2007)))`

I got this trick from a previous post: [How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator)

Comment: I followed you suggestion, but it still doesn't work. The result said :"Removed 5 rows containing missing values (position_stack)."

Comment: Ok, I think I may have figured out what happened. Does my edited answer work?