# How to tidy "price" column with "," to just a number format ? for example 1,250,000 to 1250000 (R Programming)

Tags: r, tidy, data-wrangling

I have tried to remove the comma in the price column by the following code:

```
property2 %>%
    select(Price) %>%
    str_remove_all(",")
```

but it turns out to return something like this:

```
\" \"525000\" \"300000\" \"490000\" \"4100000\" \"750000\" \"2130000\" \"585000\" \"2480000\" \"710000\" \"565000\" \"1400000\" \"880000\" \"3500000\" \"1230000\" \"3150000\" \"499000\" \"480000\" \"475000\" \"2700000\" \"6500000\" \"5100000\" \"5000000\" \"5500000\" \"480000\" \"540000\")"
Warning message:
In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

the data information

```
      Location Price Rooms add_rooms Bathrooms `Car Parks`
   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 KLCC     1,25~ 2     1                 3           2
 2 Damansa~ 6,80~ 6     NA                7          NA
 3 Dutamas  1,03~ 3     NA                4           2
 4 Cheras   NA    NA    NA               NA          NA
 5 Bukit J~ 900,~ 4     1                 3           2
 6 Taman T~ 5,35~ 4     2                 5           4
 7 Seputeh  NA    NA    NA               NA          NA
 8 Taman T~ 2,60~ 5     NA                4           4
 9 Taman T~ 1,95~ 4     1                 4           3
10 Sri Pet~ 385,~ 3     NA                2           1
```

Comment: There's something strange with your data structure. Please share sample input, `dput(head(property2["Price"], 5))` would be perfect as it will  be copy/pasteable and include all relevant class and structure information.

Comment: How was the column "price" created?

Comment: structure(list(Price = c("1,250,000", "6,800,000", "1,030,000", 
NA, "900,000")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: the data was created from importing csv

Comment: The REAL answer is to remove all formatting in your spreadsheet before saving it as csv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator)

Comment: Yes, it answered it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gsub to remove the "," and then convert to a numeric vector.

```
test_df = structure(list(Price = c("1,250,000", "6,800,000", "1,030,000", NA, "900,000")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#remove commas
test_df$Price <-gsub(",","",test_df$Price)

#Change to numeric
test_df$Price <- as.numeric(test_df$Price)

test_df$Price
```

or tidyverse style

```
test_df = structure(list(Price = c("1,250,000", "6,800,000", "1,030,000", NA, "900,000")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

test_df <- test_df %>% 
  mutate(Price = gsub(",","",Price)%>%
           as.numeric)

test_df$Price
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply and readr::parse_number, credits to: [How to read data when some numbers contain commas as thousand separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator)

```
#your data
test_df = structure(list(Price = c("1,250,000", "6,800,000", "1,030,000", NA, "900,000")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

test_df$Price<- lapply(test_df$Price, readr::parse_number)
test_df
```

[image]