# Conversion char variable in R to numeric

Tags: r

I have small data set with one column in char format. Below you can see data.

```
 test<-structure(list(txtVALUE = c("<5", "<5", "8", "<5", "9", "12", 
                                         "45", "5", "<5", "<5", "11,478", "117", "1,526", "1,642", "3,920", 
                                         "98", "8", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to convert this data from `chr` format in numeric.I tried with this command below

```
      test$txtVALUE<-as.numeric(test$txtVALUE)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

But this command does not convert data as I expected. Namely, numbers such as "1,526", "1,642", and "3,920" are converted in NAN values, although they are numbers.

So can anybody help me how to convert this data from char to numeric in the proper way without NaN for numbers?

Comment: What number do you want `"<5"` to be represented as?

Comment: If you want to ignore punctuation, you could use `readr::parse_number(test$txtVALUE)`. But that does turn `<5` into `5` which may or may not be desireable.

Comment: @SamR for "<5" can be Nan is not a problem, but the problem is numerical values such as "1,526", "1,642", and "3,920"

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-data-when-some-numbers-contain-commas-as-thousand-separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data appears to be counts so I have taken a slight liberty of assuming that it's always whole numbers. If it is not do not use this approach as it will delete decimal points as well.

However, if it is, as you want `"<5"` to be `NA`, you can use `gsub()` to replace all values that contain `"<"` with a blank string, and also delete anything which is not a number (e.g. commas in `"11,478"`).

Of course `gsub()` produces a character vector so wrap this in `as.integer()`.

```r
as.integer(gsub("\\D|<.+", "", test$txtVALUE))
#  [1]    NA    NA     8    NA     9    12    45     5    NA    NA 11478   117  1526  1642  3920    
# [16]    98     8    NA    NA    NA    NA
```